# Does "would" indicate intent but not possibility?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if "would" implies intention but not possibility, then, generally, it must only refer to persons not events. If such is the case, then this sentence, *"Would it be right to kill innocent animals?"* must be rewritten to sound like,*"Is it right to kill innocent animals?"*

Am I correct?

And if my understanding is true, does it also apply to "will", such that the sentence, *"The next world war will happen in the next three days"*, be rewritten to sound like, *"The next world war probably starts in three days"*? Please enlighten me on this issue.

Comment: You'd better ask the question at the ELL section, [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: _Would_, being a modal auxiliary verb, has a number of meanings. In particular, it has a deontic meaning _was willing to, was in the habit of_, and an epistemic meaning _be likely true, given a particular hypothesis._ It's the second meaning that you are talking about; the hypothesis is "killing of innocent animals" (whatever that may mean in context) and the question is whether the killing is possibly "right", given the fact of their "innocence" (again, for certain values of "right" and "innocence").

Comment: *"Would"* can indicate ***either*** intention ***or*** possibility. It depends on the specific construction it's being used in and on the context. You misunderstood my comment on your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

In highly traditional English, *will/would* in the **first person** is/was not used to express possibility only, but rather intent of some sort. Even so, the large majority of modern writers and speakers have deviated from this practice and use *will/would* for a neutral sense of possibility in the first person too.

At any rate, *will/would* has been used by the majority to express possibility for the **second and third person** for many centuries; it has been used as in your examples for a long time by almost everyone. There is therefore not even the hint of an issue or problem in your examples, and so there is no reason to remove the *will/would*.

Comment: It would be unusual to use a different modal verb in this sentence. How would English speakers who only use *would* for intent rephrase it?

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm not sure which sentence you mean? There are to my knowledge no speakers or writers who would not use *would* in the OP's example. For the first person, the alternative would be *should*, but none of the OP's examples are in the first person. Edit: in case it was a misunderstanding, I have emphasised *first person* in my answer; perhaps it was too inconspicuous.

Comment: "I would tell you the tale"

Comment: @kennebec: Yes, that is probably the use of *would* expressing intent/volition.

Comment: How would you rephrase the sentence *"it would be unusual to find a unicorn in the forest"*? Here, *"would"* is definitely not being used to express intent, but I don't see any way of rewriting it without doing away

Comment: @PeterShor: Nobody would rewrite that, and nobody would assume intent for *would* in the third person. I think there is a misunderstanding here.

Comment: @Cerberus: right ... I didn't see *"first person"*. But you can certainly have *would* mean intent in the third person ... *"he would be very happy to have you visit him"*.

Comment: @PeterShor: It is possible in the third person, but nobody would *assume* you meant intent by merely using *would*; there'd have to be a special context. Besides, in your example, I would not say *would* expresses intent. If it did, then your sentence would mean "he intended/wanted to be very happy to have you visit him", which it does not. The intent comes from *be happy to*, not from *would*. An example of (semi-)deontic *would* in the third person is *he would not leave her alone*.

Comment: How about *I would be very surprised to see a unicorn in the forest*? Are you saying that some people think that sentence is ungrammatical?

Comment: @PeterShor: No? I don't understand why you would ask that. In your example, *would* has no deontic/intentional meaning, otherwise it would mean "I want to be very surprised to see a unicorn in the forest". I assume that is not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Would can indicate possibility. "What would you do if you won a million pounds?"

Comment: That's the deontic sense -- what do you want to do?

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm not sure I would say that. In this question, I think the intent is implicit in asking what someone else might do, not in the word *would* itself, which I think is epistemic there for most speakers of modern English. Cf. *what would you like to drink?*: the volition/intent is in the situation, mainly in *like*, not in the word *would*. Fowler, to whom *would* in the first person must still express volition, disapproved of *I would like* for that very reason, but most speakers say it (rather than Fowler's *I should like*).